# When source and replyTo is the same, stop Camel from consuming after route stopped

Tags: java, apache-camel

Our system has configured to consume and send reply to the same queue, i.e., `JMSDestination` and `JMSReplyTo` are the same. I cannot change that right now.

In my integration test, if I set `replyToSameDestinationAllowed=true`, Camel continues to consume the reply I sent to the queue, i.e., it "captures" the source and never stop and enters a loop.

But, if I don't set it, Camel refuses to send the reply to the queue, saying this:

> JMSDestination and JMSReplyTo is the same, will skip sending a reply message to itself

That causes problem for my integration test. I want to consume the message in a separate method and assert against it.

How can I stop Camel from capturing this queue, i.e., consuming only once and ignore the rest?

At the end of my route I call `stop()` to send reply automatically.

When receiving the second message(the reply), I see this line:

> 2023-01-10 14:37:22,186 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.com.jms.EndpointMessageListener]-{Camel (camel-1) thread #19 - JmsConsumer[my.queue]}-Received Message has JMSCorrelationID [ID:hostname-1673354133272-4:1:1:10:1]

Can I use this to ignore the reply? Should I stop the route? Rollback? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I filtered out messages based on the presence of `JMSCorrelationID` header.

```
from("activemq:xxx")
    .filter(simple("${header.JMSCorrelationID} == null")) // ignore reply
    .to("direct:main");
```

Even that I don't set it in my client side code, seems that Camel will use message id to set JMSCorrelationID when sending reply if the incoming message hasn't it. If incoming message already has JMSCorrelationID, Camel will not change it, and will copy that value to the reply.(I guess that if you manually set JMSCorrelationID in client side, Camel will stop setting it for you).

So basically, message without JMSCorrelationID means it's new message which hasn't passed through my client application. I think only client side should set it, especially in my case where original message and replies are put into the same queue, where client needs a mean to filter out replies.

Also, to stop Camel from "capturing", you need to make sure other two things:

- no concurrent consuming is happening
- the queue is empty before your test(no leftover from previous test), as all my tests are running in sequential order with `@Order`.

For 1, set `replyTo(Max)ConcurrentConsumer` both to `1`, so that no concurrent consuming is happening; only one thread process this message.

```java
ActiveMQComponent component = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent(url);
// we use request-reply mode so (max)ConcurrentConsumers are not taken into account; must set "replyTo(Max)ConcurrentUsers".
// see https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/activemq-component.html
component.setReplyToConcurrentConsumers(1);
component.setReplyToMaxConcurrentConsumers(1); // seems every pod will have max consumers
```

For 2, if last test rollbacked one message and put it back to the queue, I need to consume it before running the next test.

---

At the very last, we separate the queues so even capturing is happening, it does not matter any more.